# Interval type in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spyder

```py
spark.sql("""SELECT CAST('22:00:00' AS INTERVAL HOUR TO SECOND)""").show()
```

I am executing the above query but getting the below error

```
ERROR : ParseException: 
missing ')' at 'HOUR'(line 1, pos 35)
```

Answer (score 0):

`INTERVAL HOUR TO SECOND` sql syntax format:

```
select INTERVAL '22:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND
```

Comment: Hi thank you

but i need to cast it may i know how to cast to timstamp pls ?